# Using sprintf and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having some issues writing a float variable to MySql,

The number I'm trying enter has 8 trailing zeros, ie: 0.00026400

I need to write the number to a MySql table, keeping all the zeros in tack.

I'm using the printf function to add trailing zeros before echoing it out, which works fine and would echo 0.00026400:

```
printf("%0.8f", $lastMinuteCount);
```

To get a formatted number I can write to a Mysql database, I'm using sprintf as follows:

```
$lastCountFormatted = sprintf("%0.8f", $lastMinuteCount);
```

If I echo that out, it also works fine and prints : 0.00026400

But as soon as I insert it into a MySql query, it emits the 0's and enters: 0.000264

```
UPDATE `the_table`
SET `1` = '$lastCountFormatted'
WHERE coinSymbol = '$coinSymbol'"
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I know I could probably format the number after pulling it from the database, but I'd rather just have it formatted as it gets entered if I can.

Thank you for any advice as always!

Comment: Is the type of column `1` set to `varchar` or similar? Or is it some  types of decimal?

Comment: It's set to 'float' :)

Comment: It should be `decimal`

Comment: change that to `varchar`. Float datatype won't save any trailing 0s after decimal point

Comment: But I need to pull the data as an integer, will that still be okay?

Comment: Well ;) if you need an `integer` why would you use `float` or `decimal` ?

Comment: @hex494D49: I think he meant as a `number` :-) @Ryan: you can do like `SELECT CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED) FROM table_name`

Comment: @fallen Thank you, I did mean a NUMBER. The turning the data type to Varchar seems to have worked fine, without the need for any casting. If you'd like to make an official answer, you sir, can have the point ;) Thank's alot, been busting my balls for ages trying to find the issue!

Comment: P.s @hex494D49, the decimal point type didn't work at all. In fact it kicked everything after the decimal point :/

Comment: You may use whatever you want but this value `0.00026400` shouldn't be stored into `varchar` data type column! If `decimal` is used, its arguments should be passed as well, like `decimal(9,8)` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure the type of column `1` is not decimal or unsigned, instead it should be of type `varchar` or `text` as it's supposed to store a string instead of a number. A number is not supposed to store trailing 0s after the decimal point`.`